# Google old api of profile information is not working, What is the new API URL?

Tags: google-api

Google old profile API not working now.
I used this API link before, 
(http://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/sakiremail@gmail.com?alt=json)
but it's not working now. Can't get profile information. What is the new API URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here I have created a demo app to work with. Before test please create an auth client id. Also, add an authorized redirect URI to `http://localhost` if you are checking on local.

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="javascript:" onclick="oauthSignIn()">Login</a>
    <script>
      /*
  * Create form to request access token from Google's OAuth 2.0 server.
  */
 function oauthSignIn() {
   // Google's OAuth 2.0 endpoint for requesting an access token
   var oauth2Endpoint = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth';

   // Create <form> element to submit parameters to OAuth 2.0 endpoint.
   var form = document.createElement('form');
   form.setAttribute('method', 'GET'); // Send as a GET request.
   form.setAttribute('action', oauth2Endpoint);

   // Parameters to pass to OAuth 2.0 endpoint.
   var params = {'client_id': 'YOUR_APP_CLIENT_ID',
     'redirect_uri': 'AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URI',
     'response_type': 'token',
     'scope': 'profile',
     'include_granted_scopes': 'true',
     'state': 'pass-through value'};

   // Add form parameters as hidden input values.
   for (var p in params) {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  input.setAttribute('name', p);
  input.setAttribute('value', params[p]);
  form.appendChild(input);
   }

   // Add form to page and submit it to open the OAuth 2.0 endpoint.
   document.body.appendChild(form);
   form.submit();
 }
 
 var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);

 var hashresult = hash.split('&').reduce(function (result, item) {
  var parts = item.split('=');
  result[parts[0]] = parts[1];
  return result;
 }, {});
 
 if(hashresult.access_token){
  console.log(hashresult.access_token);
  fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token='+hashresult.access_token)
  .then(function(response) {
   return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(userdata) {
  console.log(userdata);
  });
 }
 
    </script>
 
  </body>
</html>
```